# How can I make PyCharm recognize method parameters when extracting a method?

Tags: python, pycharm

PyCharm has a few refactoring features. One of them is the `Extract Method` feature. It usually does not work as I would expect. e.g. a minimal example:

```
a  = 2

b = a**2
```

after selecting `a**2` and performing the `Extract Method` feature I am getting:

```
a  = 2


def method_name():
    return a ** 2


b = method_name()
```

What I would expect and wish is the following:

```
a  = 2


def method_name(a): #a should be a parameter...
    return a ** 2


b = method_name(a) #...and should be passed here
```

Is there a way to somehow force PyCharm to recognize parameters? Or is it just how this feature works? In that case is there any other way to accomplish this in PyCharm?

Comment: In most cases I see exactly the behavior you would want.  I think the issue in this case is that `a` is a global variable.  If you do the same thing but all of your code is within another function definition it works exactly as you desire.

Comment: @Malcolm yes, that works! Thanks!

Comment: I have to say I am not sure why PyCharm doesn't give you the option of making `a` a parameter when it is a global variable in a global expression.  It is just that this is the problem you are seeing.  I suspect the fact that the mechanism is called "Extract Method" means that the developers have assumed that you are obviously working on methods within a class and so haven't considered your use case and noted the failure.